# modifying d3's force layout "annealling" schedule

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a d3 force layout graph viz working pretty nicely, but it often gets 'stuck' prematurely. For example, nodes are jiggling towards a good placement, and if 'bump' them (injecting a bit of randomness to their placement and `start()` again, they finally get there. The problem also gets worse if I decrease `friction`, because the users think it's too frenetic.

I see mention of 'annealling' (ala simulated annealling) in the [`force.js` source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js), and the exposed `alpha` parameter is one key ingredient. I'm wondering if anyone has figured out how to manage the general annealling schedule directly (*without* patching `force.js`!)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Modifying anything that's not exposed will require changing the source code.

Comment: If a graph is too big or hairy to layout nicely in one shot, I might try adding the nodes over time and restarting the layout on every add. Its even better if there's a logic to it like a time or type component for the nodes.

Comment: @Lars, sorry i was unclear.  `alpha` seems the only exposed parameter, but i can only do so much with it.  i'm asking whether there is some way to accomplish more general cooling schedules, in a d3-ic way, or do i need to do a local patch?  @Andrew, i want this to be a graph viz tool modified by the user, over a fixed graph.

Comment: @rikb The `force.alpha()` method lets you set alpha to whatever value you want, so you could try adjusting it from within the `"tick"` handler. On line 60 of the source code you linked to, alpha gets adjusted like so: `alpha *= .99` (until it decreases below .005). So, theoretically, if on every tick you set `alpha *= 1/.995` the layout would take about twice as long to settle. Maybe...

Comment: I mean something like this: `force.on('tick', function() { force.alpha( force.alpha() / .995 ); })`

Comment: hi @meetamit.  right, i have a `myAlpha *= annealDecay; force.alpha( myAlpha );` hack in my `tick()` function, and it helps some.  i am also adding noise to node positions before restarting, ...

Answer (score 0):

The core of the answer is @meetamit's comment (to accelerate the decay of alpha).  You can also stop calling the layout when it gets below a threshold, and you can also deal with the 'jitter' by adding transitions to your node/link movements.

```
animationStep = 200;
force.on('tick', function() {
    node.transition().ease('linear').duration(animationStep)
        .attr('transform', function(d) { 
             //your node transitions here 
        });
    var alpha = force.alpha();
    force.stop();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!alpha > 0.001) {
        force.alpha(alpha * 0.9);
      }
    }, animationStep);
  };
  force.on('tick', tick);
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a way to _decelerate_ in fact but, anyway, the simplest way to manage alpha is to put `force.alpha(force.alpha()/0.99*myDecay)` at the end of the `tick` callback. This reverses the decay applied by the layout (which is 0.99) and replaces it with your own rate of geometric decay.